# Is there a theory for "transactional" sequences of failing and no-fail actions?

Tags: theory, error-handling, transaction

My question is about writing transaction-like functions that execute sequences of actions, some of which may fail. It is related to the general C++ principle "destructors can't throw," no-fail property, and maybe also with multi-phase transactions or exception safety. However, I'm thinking about it in language-neutral terms. My concern is with correctly designing error handling in C++ functions that must be reliable. I would like to know what the concepts below are called so that I can learn more about them.

I'm sorry that I can't ask the question more directly. Since I don't know this area I have provided an example to explain my question. The question is at the end. Here goes:

Consider a sequence of steps or actions executed sequentially, where actions belong to one of two classes: those that always succeed, and those that may fail. In the examples below:

- `S` stands for an action that always succeeds (called "no-fail" in some settings).
- `F` stands for an action that may fail (for example, it might fail to allocate memory or do I/O that could fail).

Consider a sequences of actions (executed sequentially from left to right):

```
S->S->S->S
```

Since each action in the sequence above succeeds, the whole sequence succeeds.

On the other hand, the following sequence may fail because the last action may fail:

```
S->S->S->F
```

So, **claim:** a sequence has the no-fail (S) property if and only if all of its actions are no-fail.

Now, I'm interested in action sequences that form "atomic transactions", with "failure atomicity," i.e. where either the whole sequence completes successfully, or there is no effect. I.e. if some action fails, the earlier ones must be rolled back. This requires that any successfully executed actions prior to a failing action must always be able to be rolled back. Consider the sequence:

```
S->S->S->F
S<-S<-S
```

In the example above, the first row is the forward path of the transaction, and the second row are inverse actions (executed from right to left) that can be used to roll back if the final top row actions fails.

It seems to me that for a transaction to support failure atomicity, the following invariant must hold:

**Claim:** To support *failure atomicity* (either successful completion, or complete roll-back on failure) all actions preceding the latest failable (F) action on the forward path (marked * in the example below) must have no-fail (S) inverses. The following is an example of a sequence that supports failure atomicity:

```
         *
S->F->F->F
S<-S<-S
```

Further, if we want the transaction to be able to attempt cancellation mid-way through, but still guarantee either full completion or full rollback then we need the following property:

**Claim:** To support *failure atomicity and cancellation* mid-way through execution, in the face of errors in the inverse (cancellation) path, all actions following the earliest failable (F) inverse on the reverse path (marked *) must be no-fail (S).

```
F->F->F->S->S
S<-S<-F<-F
      *
```

I believe that these two conditions guarantee that an abortable/cancelable transaction will never get "stuck".

My questions are:

*What is the study and theory of these properties called? are my claims correct? and what else is there to know?*

UPDATE 1: Updated terminology: what I previously called "robustness" is called **atomicity** in the database literature.

UPDATE 2: Added explicit reference to [failure atomicity](http://jtechies.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/item-64-strive-for-failure-atomicity.html), which seems to be a thing.

Comment: Having no-fail inverses is sufficient but not necessary. There may be actions with no inverses (because they map 2+ inputs to the same output), but if you keep a record of which transformations you performed, it doesn't matter that there is no inverse. Alternatively, if you kept the previous states around, you don't need to do undo anything. That said, using persistent data structures is by far the easiest way to support this kind of rollback behavior; by keeping the old state around, you get rollbacks for free. Only works if the state is under your control though.

Comment: @Doval Programming without side effects is cool, but I have to deal with subsystems that may fail, and that are outside my control. I'm not sure what you mean by "if you keep a record of which transformations you performed, it doesn't matter that there is no inverse"? how to you reverse a transformation if there is no inverse?

Comment: Suppose you have a mutable `int` variable `x`, and you overwrite it with its absolute value. This is a function with no inverse because if `x` now holds `5`, its prior state could've been either `-5` or `5`. But if you keep a log stating "I changed `x` from -5 to 5" it doesn't matter that the function you applied to get to the new state has no inverse. This is generally how databases and file systems make sure they can roll back if, say, the power were to go out mid-transaction. Of course, this is really just another form of "keep the old state around", except you have to do it yourself.

Comment: @Doval, thanks, that makes sense. I guess saved state could be considered equivalent to a no-fail inverse if there is a no-fail way of reinstating it.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but have you looked at the way ACID principles are implemented in databases? It seems to fit the bill and I bet there's plenty of theory around the ideas.

Comment: It's probably not what you're looking for, but you might be interested in [patch theory](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Understanding_Darcs/Patch_theory)

Comment: @DanS thanks for the suggestion. I have not looked into DB implementations (was hoping for something a bit more straight forward and general) but it's a good idea and I shall do that. I suppose for writing C functions the main properties are Atomicity and Consistency.

Comment: @paul thanks, yes that is interesting. In the present context however I am concerned not only with actions with inverses (or "undo") capability, but also with actions that may exhibit non-deterministic failure (or conversely, have the no-fail property).

Comment: @RossBencina Perhaps you could combine patches with some sort of monad return value? Here's a nice [intro tutorial](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) if you're not familiar. I'd think you could accumulate a rollback function during processing and return that in the failure case.

Comment: @paul my functions aren't pure. I'm in C++ and actions include things like opening and closing files. I guess I'm interested in understanding the theory of when I can and can't do as you suggest.

Comment: @paul thanks for the fsharpforfunandprofit link though, that looks very relevant to me whether or not it answers the question.

Comment: @paul Speaking of monads, you could probably implement the transaction log ("changed this, changed that, ...") using the [Writer monad](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more).

Comment: @Doval Yeah, that would work on the forward way, but I'm not sure if it would work on the rollback: if you did the writer as a monad transformer on top of the monad performing the sequence of operations, then when a failure branch was taken returning a rollback function (if that's how you implemented it) then that function would likely be run outside of the monad stack, so the rollbacks wouldn't be logged using the writer (unless you did so explicitly outside of the transform stack). I wonder if it would be possible to run the rollbacks still in the monad?

Comment: Perhaps out of scope, but I have found that in real-world examples of this sort of thing, the whole invert-to-get-back-to-a-good-state is actually not as robust as a "journaling" approach where the work is done and committed atomically as the last step (journaling file systems, etc). This is because a power-failure is often beyond your control. However, as far as theory around this stuff goes with respect to invertability, it makes me think of the [memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).

Comment: This would appear to be related to the [Compensating Transaction Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589804.aspx).

Comment: A related question at TCS.SE: [Is there a 'process algebra' to describe ACID transactions on a database?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19958/is-there-a-process-algebra-to-describe-acid-transactions-on-a-database)